# Dump mobile memory

Tags: android, memory, adb, kernel-module, galaxy

i want to dump my mobiles memory with lime but during the process i faced some problems.
1.Downloaded kernel source and building, zImage is created.

2.Change Makefile for lime as the guide says and then i make lime.(problem in this step despite the lime.ko file and lime-3.8.0-29-generic.ko file for my case has been created)

3.Command ./adb push ~/lime-forensics/src/lime-3.8.0-29-generic.ko /sdcard/lime.ko pushed succesfully

4.Rooted phone accepts access for adb shell as root and lime insmod command fails in order to dump the memory

The problem is when in adb shell type command insmod /sdcard/lime.ko “path=/sdcard/ram.lime format=lime”
 gives this error

```
 # insmod /sdcard/lime.ko "path=/sdcard/ram.lime format=lime>
insmod: init_module '/sdcard/lime.ko' failed (Exec format error).
```

What possible mistake i made and what to do to resolve this error and go on?

Comment: are you compiling for the correct architecture/ABI?

Comment: i suppose so but how to test if it is the right can i check it somewhere which i use

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel is not clean. Please clean & rebuild.
+ look for your compiler options.